# Has Tyrion been right on any major points in season 7?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In season 7 of *Game of Thrones* Tyrion has a bit of a failure streak going

> - His initial war plans are completely countered by Jamie
>
>   He fails to convince Dany to not melt Randyll and Dickon
>
>   He fails to convince Dany to not risk herself to attack the Lannister army
>
>   He fails to convince Dany to create a succession plan
>
>   He fails to convince Dany to not risk herself to save Jon
>
>   His "success" during on the treaty with Cersei is actually a failure

As far as I can tell the only successful thing he has done was to convince Dany to let Jon mine the Dragonglass.

Is there anything else that Tyrion has had success at this season?

Comment: I don't think his plans were wrong just because the Lannisters/Euron countered them. If you lose a battle you didn't make the wrong choice 99% of the time, your opponents just made a better one. For example, see Robb vs Jaime he fakes a battle that he loses yet it was a distraction.

Answer (score 7):

He is right about one thing - the most important thing - that Daenerys should not go north of the Wall with her dragons. However, because of his previous failures, Daenerys does not listen to him -

> TYRION: You can't! The most important person in the world can't fly to the
> most dangerous place in the world.
>
> DAENERYS: Who else can?
>
> TYRION: No one. They knew the risk when they left. You can't win the throne if you're dead. You can't break the wheel if you're
> dead.
>
> DAENERYS: So what would you have me do?
>
> TYRION: Nothing. Sometimes nothing is the hardest thing to do. If you die we're all lost. Everyone, everything.
>
> DAENERYS: You told me to do nothing before and I've listened to you. I'm not
> doing nothing again.

Tyrion's apparently poor advice causes many losses throughout season 7, which in turn leads to Daenerys' critical error of taking her dragons beyond the wall.

Comment: But his reasoning was dead wrong. So in essence, he was wrong in this as well.

Comment: I don't think you can say he's "wrong" - he didn't know that a dragon might be turned, but he was still right that they shouldn't go. "If you die we're all lost. Everyone, everything." I think that's correct reasoning here considering how important Daenerys and her dragons are in the fight against the Night King.

Comment: Danaerys is also countering two of Tyrion's claims, in a way that seems to contradict. She goes beyond the Wall and risks her life, but then she also refuses to talk about who inherits her throne when she's gone. I think this (combined with actions like burning the Tarlys) shows hints of Danaerys only considering herself and her power, caring little for what happens to her people after she's gone (she seems to not care since she won't be there to care anyway). Tyrion, while having made mistakes, seems to be on the moral high ground here. So you can consider his **advice** to still be right.

Answer (score -2):

Well, not exactly success, but he figured out both Danny and Jon are falling for each other.

Something more of importance:

- He supported inviting Jon and invited him himself
- it's his plan that they can capture one wight... oh, actually that was kinda success, except both Night King and Cercei actually profited from it. But that helped to hook up Jon and Danny :)

So actually nothing except for romance which makes him now even more worried than before :D

**Edit:** actually when I think about it, he did have a part in one success. The fact that he attacked Castelry Rock and that Jamie anticipated that, resulted in joined forces of Lannisters and other lords marching on Highgarden. And that is a bit of success afterwards, since they were out in the open so Danny can use dragon and Dothrakies. Since everyone including Jon advices her against dragonfire in the cities, this created oportunity to demonstrate power and dragon. Now lords are terrified and soldiers bent the knee, which was far more effective than having few more thousands of soldiers from Highgarden. Lords of the Reach sided with Cercei anyway, so although they lost Highgarden and allies, they delievered the punch that more or less would won the war for them IF they had time to continue.

So, being clever caused Jamie to be more clever and made dragon attack possible without civilian victims.

But willingly and planning military strategies, I guess he was a big failure this season.

Comment: One might argue that getting an aunt and her nephew to "hook up" isn't necessarily a *good* thing :P

Comment: Naaah, it's great thing. It is feudal system, it is fantasy world and they are Targaryens :) What could possible be bad about it?

Comment: Just because the Targaryens are OK with it doesn't mean that Jon is... he wasn't raised that way. It's a point of conflict that we don't know how he will react to.

Comment: @Catija Those are modern sensibilities which are largely at odds with the feudal Europe style that GRRM has intentionally created.  Especially so amongst nobles and royalty, who were often convinced that breeding with commoners was a grave sin. I understand GRRM was originally going to have some sort of love triangle with Jon/Arya/Tyrion, so he was hardly going to take incest off the table (as if that wasn't clear with Jaime and Cersei already). Also, Tyrion likely has no idea that they're related.